# Maths recursive defintition

Tags: functions

I could potentially be extremely happy today :P well i've been stuck on a question for some time, i'm pretty poor at Maths and revising for my exam in January... Anyway if i understand this question correctly then it's extremely easy; in fact it seems too easy so i'm not sure
Consider the following recursive definition of the set $X$:

Base case $-1 \in X$
Recursive Case: If $x \in X$ then $2x \in X$ and $3x \in X$.

State whether $-4 \in X$, $9 \in X$ and $-10 \in X$. Show how you derived your answers.

My answer

9 is a straight no since it's a positive number, and the base case is negative. Since you're not timing by negatives throughout the recursive, it can never be positive.

-4 is yes since your base case is 1  and yhe recursive case allows you to times by 2 therefore if you do 1x2 and then 2x2=4 so yes. (obviously with the minus sign :P )

-10 is no because there is no possible ways of combining -10 using the base case -1 while timing either by 2 or 3 using recursive case

so the answer is -4 yes, 9 no, -10 no

Comment: Your answer says you can't get $-10$ because you caan't get $-10$. Perhaps something like if $x$ is not divisible by $5$, then neither $2x$ nor $3x$ is divisible by $5$. So since $-1$ is not divisible by $5$, $\dots$. Or maybe just say the only elements of $X$ that are $\le 10$ are $-1,-2,-3,-4,-6,=8,-9$.

Answer (score 2):

By induction all numbers of the form $-(2^x\cdot 3^y)$ for non negative integers $x$ and $y$ are in $X$).

Proof: $-(2^0\cdot 3^0)$ is in $X$.

now suppose the number $-(2^a\cdot 3^b)$ is in X. Then the numbers $-(2^{a+1}\cdot 3^b)$and $-(2^a\cdot 3^{b+1})$are also in $X$

Yes, you can easily see that only negative numbers are there and $10$ is not of the form $-(2^x\cdot 3^y)$ so it isn't there. While $-4=-(2^2\cdot 3^0)$ is.

Comment: so i'm correct? would i get full marks or isn't mine mathematical enough? if it's a 5 mark question

Comment: thank you btw for replying

Comment: I would give you full marks, The question didn't ask to say which numbers where in the set, it only asked if those examples where in the list, and I think you did that. Glad to help,(if this does help that is)

Comment: If you like my solution would you consider accepting it or upvoting it? Otherwise please tell me why it doesn't help and I can try to make it better.